# AppVeyor error while building csproj

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, .net-core, appveyor

I have a mixed solution which is using some `.net core` dlls and one `.Net Framework 4.5.2` dll. My VS2015U3 is fine with this solution but when I'm trying to build it with `AppVeyor` I'm getting an error:

> "C:\projects\remoteclient\RemoteClient\RemoteClient.sln" (default
>   target) (1) ->
>   "C:\projects\remoteclient\RemoteClient\test\RemoteClient.WcfTest\RemoteClient.WcfTest.csproj"
>   (default target) (5) ->
>   "C:\projects\remoteclient\RemoteClient\src\RemoteClient.Client\RemoteClient.Client.csproj"
>   (default target) (6) ->
>   C:\projects\remoteclient\RemoteClient\src\RemoteClient.Client\RemoteClient.Client.csproj(1,1):
>   error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the project must be the
>   MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003
>   format, please add
>   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the
>    element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or
>   1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

However, my file is obiosly in `2003 format` ([link for a reference](https://github.com/Pzixel/RemoteClient/blob/master/RemoteClient/test/RemoteClient.WcfTest/RemoteClient.WcfTest.csproj)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
```

[Here is link](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Pzixel/remoteclient) to AppVeyor build.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: It requires the latest .NET Core SDK. Read AppVeyor manual to see how to configure that.

Comment: @LexLi Ok. Because I was confused by official MS documentation which is saying that I need nothing but `os` setting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/preview3/tools/using-ci-with-cli

Comment: drop a comment there to blame them please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that your solution is built in Visual Studio 2017. I enabled beta `Visual Studio 2017 RC` build worker image for you on AppVeyor. To use it you have to set `image: Visual Studio 2017 RC`in `appveyor.yml` or select `image: Visual Studio 2017 RC` in Environment tab in UI. Note that build start is slower with beta image, it is expected.

If you are not familiar with `appveyor.yml` structure I strongly recommend to use UI for initial configuration and then use `Export YAML` menu to create initial `appveyor.yml`.

Also please ensure that you can successfully build your solution locally with `msbuild` (not VS).

Comment: I setted `image: Visual Studio 2017 RC`, however, it fails with `error : Duplicate 'Compile' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Compile' items from your project directory by default.`

Comment: It is probably [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shaneosborne/2017/01/31/breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-2017-rc-build-26127-00/) issue. Seems that this behavior was introduced [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/624). What specific version of VS you have locally? I assume you can locally build with both VS and msbuild.

Comment: Thank you, i'l check it this morning and come back with results.

Comment: So' i'm back. I had been waiting for `VS 2017` release and it came. Today I fixed all issues and built the solution. It succeed and I pushed it into my repository. But I'm still getting multiple error such as `The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found`.

Comment: @Alex you should post your yaml file somewhere (i.e. pastebin) so we could have a look and compare issues